# Where does the new notepad with Windows 11 save the window position?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, notepad, windows-11

For Windows 11, the location HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Notepad is no longer used to save window size and position for notepad. Exploring and testing do not provide a new registry location for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) when opening and closing Notepad, you will see values read from a registry key that looks like the following:

[image: Process Monitor Screen Capture]

E.g.

> Notepad.exe RegQueryValue \REGISTRY\WC\Silo16cb54f5-9094-87ae-d593-50e2dc13f03cuser_sid\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\iWindowPosY    SUCCESS Type:
> REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 669

You will note that the start of the path isn't a commonly seen [registry hive](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives) such as HKCU, HKLM, etc..

What is \REGISTRY\WC? Well looking under:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist

You can see the various .dat files that back the possible registry hives, so in the case of Notepad, the .dat files on my computer are under:

C:\ProgramData\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_8wekyb3d8bbwe\S-1-5-21-4143797489-525809663-3828285892-1047\SystemAppData\Helium\Cache

*Where:* The SID value, in this case S-1-5-21-4143797489-525809663-3828285892-1047, is the SID of the account running Notepad.

If you run from a command prompt: `whoami /user` you will see the SID for the account running the command prompt.

So to answer your question, the configuration is contained in the .dat files.

Comment: Unfortunately WC hives load when applications open and unload when applications close, rendering them unusable for anything else. In this case I wrote my own lightweight text viewer just to throw text on the screen with no edit capability.